# Json as .textValue( ) - Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

My need is to identify the pattern of input which passess this particular code. I don't understand why value of errormessage, though it is passed as string, gives null on `node.get("errorMessage").textValue()`. Please favour on the same.Ignore encoder/decoder.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException{

        String err="{\"statusMessage\":\"InternalServerError\",\"status\":\"500\"}";
        String errormessage="{\"errorMessage\":"+err+"}";
        ByteBuffer buff=Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(errormessage);
        String response=Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(buff).toString();           
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(response);
           try{
           String errorMessageText = node.get("errorMessage").textValue();
            JsonNode errorNode = mapper.readTree(errorMessageText);
            String status = String.valueOf(errorNode.get("status").asInt());
            String statusMessage = errorNode.get("statusMessage").textValue();
            System.out.println(status);
            System.out.println(statusMessage);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the returned value of `errorMessage` is `JsonNode`. So you first get `JsonNode` and after you can get the values.

```
JsonNode errorNode = node.get("errorMessage"); 
String status = String.valueOf(errorNode.get("status").asInt()); 
String statusMessage = errorNode.get("statusMessage").textValue();
```

If you want to get `errorMessage` as `string` than you can try:

```
node.get("errorMessage").toString()
```